# Intent Service not called

Tags: android

Here is my service class

```
package com.example.com.listener;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.example.com.R;
import com.example.com.listener.GCMRegistrationListener;
import com.example.com.util.Constants;
import com.example.com.web.RawRequest;
import com.example.com.web.WebRequest;

public class GCMRegistrationService extends IntentService{

    private static final String TAG = "GCMRegistrationService";
    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

    public GCMRegistrationService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {

            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            sendRegistrationToServer(token,sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF,""));
            Toast.makeText(this,"This is your token " + token,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("token", token);
            // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
            // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
            // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Constants.GCM_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
            // [END register_for_gcm]
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
            // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Constants.GCM_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Persist registration to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token,String email) {
        WebRequest request= new RawRequest(this,Constants.SEND_GCM_TOKEN, Request.Method.POST);
        Map<String,String> requestParams= new HashMap<>();
        requestParams.put(Constants.GCM_TOKEN_LABEL,token);
        requestParams.put(Constants.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF,email);
        request.sendRequest(new GCMRegistrationListener(), requestParams, null);

    }

}
```

Here is the code I used to start the service:

```
Intent gcmRegister= new Intent(context,GCMRegistrationService.class);
                 context.startService(gcmRegister);
```

Manifest file entry is:
    Manifest package is com.example.com

and service entry is

```
 <service android:name=".listener.GCMRegistrationService" android:exported="false" />
```

Unfortunately my service is not running. Please help.

Comment: please share the <manifest...> tag (because of the package)

Comment: Information added in question.

Comment: Is the service in a sub-package (listener) of com.example.com?

Comment: Yes, It's a sub package. However I just added onStartCommand method and it is called. However OnHandleIntent is still not called.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by removing onStartCommand method.

Comment: good you solved your issue by urself :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your data according to your requirement ,Allow this service tag outside the closing activity tag in manifest file :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.twitter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"               
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TwitterTwoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>  
    <service android:name="tfe.rma.ciss.be.Server"/>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Adding superclass to onCreate super.onCreate() and change onStart by onStartCommand (plus its superclass super.onStartCommand().

```
 package tfe.rma.ciss.be;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlrpc.android.MethodCall;
import org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCServer;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

public class Server extends IntentService {
    public String myData="";
    public String streamTitle = "",path="";

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("Server", ">>>onCreate()");
    }

    public Server() {
        super("Server");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Server", ">>>handlingIntent()");
        try {
            ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8214);
            XMLRPCServer server = new XMLRPCServer();
            Log.d("Server", ">>>opening on port" + socket);

            while (true) {
                Socket client = socket.accept();
                MethodCall call = server.readMethodCall(client);
                String name = call.getMethodName();

                if (name.equals("newImage")) {
                    ArrayList<Object> params = call.getParams();
                    // assume "add" method has two Integer params, so no checks done
                    myData = (String)( params.get(0));
                    //int i1 = (Integer) params.get(1);
                    server.respond(client, new Object[] {200});
                    /*intent = new Intent (this, ParseFunction.class);
                    startService (intent);  */

                    Toast.makeText(this, myData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                    Log.d("ParseFunction", ">>>Started()"); 

                    Intent i = new Intent( this, B.class );
                    i.putExtra( "Azo", myData);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity( i );
                } else {
                    server.respond(client, null);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explaining what you changed and why is essential information

Comment: he is writing wrong package name as you can see his package name in manifest

Comment: My bad. Corrected in question.

Comment: Yes she is from Rajasthan  :)

Comment: Now also your intent service is not getting called ?

Comment: Yeah. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

GCM register() has been deprecated. Use InstanceID to perform general GCM registration management. as shown below , use google play lib to get it.

```
Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration event is received");
    String token;

    try {
        token = InstanceID.getInstance(context).getToken(context.getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token retrieved from google cloud: " + token);
        //
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // exponential back off
        Log.e(TAG, "IO error occurred, going to back off. backoffIndexGCM:" + backoffIndexGCM);
        exponentialBackOff.postDelayed(exponentialBackOffGCMRegisterRun, 1000 * backoffIndexGCM);
        backoffIndexGCM *= 2;
        // should not wait more than 1000 sec in any circumstance.
        backoffIndexGCM %= 1000;
    }
```